# In React (not react native): The behavior for Date objects stored in Firestore is going to change AND YOUR APP MAY BREAK

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I am getting the following error message in a react app:

> @firebase/firestore: Firestore (4.13.0):  The behavior for Date
>   objects stored in Firestore is going to change AND YOUR APP MAY BREAK.

Did anybody see this in a react application, and fixed it? Can you share your insights/code?

I saw references to the same problem for an **angular application**:
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/726

And for a **react native application** (where the advise is not to do anything regarding this issue):
https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1024

Answer (score 1):

```
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "***********************",
  authDomain: "***********************",
  databaseURL: "***********************",
  projectId: "***********************",
  storageBucket: "***********************",
  messagingSenderId: "***********************"
});

const settings = {timestampsInSnapshots: true};
firebase.firestore().settings(settings);
```

Just add the above two statements in your code where you are configuring your firebase/firestore code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my example. Just make sure you follow an order of commands.

//Config

> const firebaseConfig = {
>    apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
>
> authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
>
> databaseURL: "XXXXXXXXXXX",
>
> projectId: "XXXXXXXXXXX",
>
> storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
>
> messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
>   };

//Init

> firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

//Date object

> const settings = { timestampsInSnapshots: true };
>
> firebase.firestore().settings(settings);